# Let $T:F^2 \rightarrow F^2$ be the linear mapping defined by $T(a_1,a_2)=(a_1+a_2,a_1)$.Checking that T is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:F^2 \rightarrow F^2$ be the linear mapping defined by $T(a_1,a_2)=(a_1+a_2,a_1)$.

Checking that T is one-to-one.

So to check one-to-one, let $a_1+a_2=0$ and $a_1=0$, we get $a_1=a_2=0$

My question is for N(T)=0, does that mean we need to find all vectors $x \in F^2$ such that x=0? Just concept checking.

Comment: You have to find all $x \in F^2$ such that $F(x) = 0$. If this holds only for $x = 0$, then $F$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, intead of proving directly that $T$ is one-to-one, you proved that$$\ker T=\{(0,0)\}.\tag1$$No problem about that, since that assertion is equivalent to the assertion that $T$ is one-to-one. And, yes, you proved correctly that you have $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

We could represent this transformation as the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since $A$ is invertible, the mapping is one-to-one.